# How to get latest distinct rows in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple database table as follows :

[image]

In this I need to extract featureId, name and latest createdTime(i.e. max)

I have tried something like :

```
    select distinct featureId, 
           name, 
           max(createdTime) as createdTime 
      from feature 
  group by featureId;
```

But it returns wrong result :

[image]

I need result containing name with max createdTime.

```
1234    Test3    3
1235    Test5    5
1236    Test7    7
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please mention in comment why downvote?

Comment: Don't use distinct and group by in same select, no use of it ... 2nd thing is for your problem, look for row_count() over (partition by 'Column' order by 'column' to be your inner select, youll figure it out after, and for 3rd and last, reason of down vote is probably because same question was asked thousand of times, with bit googling you would find answer .. ps: wasn't me who down voted it

Comment: @Veljko89 Thanks for your quick help. With your help I have achieved my expected result. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems your google result is not good. let's do this again.

```
     select 
          a.featureId,
          a.name,
          a.createTime
     from feature a
     where exists(
     select 1 from 
          (select featureId,max(createTime)as createTime from feature group by featureId)b
              where b.featureId = a.featureID and b.createTime = a.createTime  
     )
```

or you can just use inner join

```
     select 
          a.featureId,
          a.name,
          a.createTime
     from feature a
     inner join 
     (select featureId,max(createTime)as createTime from feature group by featureId)b
     on a.featureId = b.featureId and a.createTime = b.createTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like :

```
SELECT 
      featureId, name, createdTime
FROM  feature 
where createdTime
IN    (SELECT max(createdTime) from feature group by featureId) ;
```

and achieved my expected result.

```
1234    Test3    3
1235    Test5    5
1236    Test7    7
```

Comment: nah man,in this case, you maybe could get the right result,but if 1234 got max create time is 3 and 1235 have create time 3,4,5 and it's max is 5. you use IN like that would get 1235  4 for output

Answer (score 0):

Remove GROUP By or Distinct from your query, you should use only one in your Mysql Select query, distinct or group by.